# Cassandra ColumnFamilyInputformat throwing IncompatibleClassChangeError on Hadoop 2.2

Tags: hadoop2

When I tried to run a simple map reduce program talking to Cassandra, I get the following error. I am using Hadoop 2.2 and Cassandra 2.0.2. Can someone who solved this problem please respond back with the solution?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
        at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.AbstractColumnFamilyInputFormat.getSplits(AbstractColumnFamilyInputFormat.java:116)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:491)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:508)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:392)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1268)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1265)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1265)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1286)
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm getting the same problem (using Spark, but I don't think it matters).